# Appending to XML file but its only appending to the first set of elements

Tags: php, html, xml

I have an XML file that is generated from another program but I would like to append to the XML so that the other program still can read the data. I worte a PHP script to make the appedning easier but I am not able to get it to work the way I want to. As it's written right now I can append to the XML file but it will only append to the first set of elements.

```
<?php
$file = "RouteSymbol.xml";
if (file_exists($file)) {
$orders = simplexml_load_file($file,"SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOERROR |  LIBXML_ERR_NONE) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
echo "<table border='1'>";
 foreach ($orders->xpath(".//HighwayRoutingData") as $routingPoints){
    $tag=(string)$routingPoints->tag;
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>".$tag."</td>";

     
     $stringArr =array();
     foreach($routingPoints->xpath(".//destinationSymbols//string") as $symbol){
     $string=(string)$symbol;

     $stringArr[] = $string;

}
$stringImp = implode(',', $stringArr);
echo "<td>";
echo  $stringImp;
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
?>
<form method="POST" action="addSymbol.php">
    <input type="text" name="symbol">
<?php
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="location" value="'.$tag.'">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="fileName" value="'.$file.'">';
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="addSymbol" value="ADD">
</form>
<?php
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<a href='#'>Delete</a>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";  
}
echo "</table>";
}else{
            echo "Invalid request!";
        }
```

The appending code

```
<?php 
$fileName = "";
if (isset($_POST['addSymbol'])) {
    $xml = new DomDocument();
    //$fileName = $_POST['fileName'];
    $xml->load('RouteSymbol.xml');

    $symbol = $_POST['symbol'];

    $rootTag = $xml->getElementsByTagName('destinationSymbols')->item(0);
    $symbolTag = $xml->createElement("string", $symbol);

    $rootTag->appendChild($symbolTag);
    $xml->save($_POST['fileName']);
    //echo $fileName;
    header("location:trainRouting.php");
}else{
    echo "Could not Load".$fileName;
}
```

The XML file that im appending to, right now the script seems to only want to append to the @I80 destination symbols. When it does append it also appends to the right of the current set of string tags instead of below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfHighwayRoutingData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <HighwayRoutingData>
    <tag>@I80</tag>
    <destinationSymbols>
      <string>SFO</string>
      <string>OAK</string>
      <string>EMR</string>
      <string>ELC</string>
      <string>RIC</string>
      <string>SPB</string>
    <string>HER</string><string>HER</string></destinationSymbols>
  </HighwayRoutingData>
    <HighwayRoutingData>
    <tag>@SR24</tag>
    <destinationSymbols>
      <string>OAK</string>
      <string>ORI</string>
      <string>LFY</string>
      <string>WCR</string>
    </destinationSymbols>
  </HighwayRoutingData>
  <HighwayRoutingData>
    <tag>@US101</tag>
    <destinationSymbols>
      <string>SFO</string>
      <string>SSC</string>
      <string>MIL</string>
      <string>PAO</string>
    </destinationSymbols>
  </HighwayRoutingData>

  </ArrayOfHighwayRoutingData>
```

There's a code pen if it helps https://codepen.io/dsflyerds/pen/BawZzMx

Comment: You would need to show the code which adds the data to help.

Comment: `I would like to append to the XML` - where is this code that appends new content? I see the above reads the existing file and generates HTML output but I cannot see the appending or modifying of the XML

Comment: Incidentally the above code that reads the XMl and generates HTML content could be done with an XSLT stylesheet?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius sorry I forgot to include it. It's there now

Comment: When the form is submitted do you wish to add a new element to each `HighwayRoutingData` section or to a specific one depending upon the values supplied in the form elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an assumption about the way the form is intended to `update` the XML so rather than have individual forms for each table row / `HighwayRoutingData` node a single form would suffice in conjunction with using an `array` syntax for field names.

I assumed that whatever text is written into the text field is to be appended to the relevant `destinationSymbols` node within the XML based upon the assigned `tag` within the XML and the HTML table rather than being appended into ALL `destinationSymbols` nodes. To modify that behaviour however is fairly straightforward. You'll note there are no `SimpleXML` functions as I have never used it so it simply uses DOMDocument & DOMXPath.

```
<?php

    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    /*
        We should ONLY proceed if these POST fields
        are actually set.
    */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset(
        $_POST['location'],
        $_POST['fileName'],
        $_POST['symbol']
    )){

        /*
            Prepare filters
        */
        $args=array(
            'symbol'    =>  array('filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED, 'flags' => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY ),
            'location'  =>  array('filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED, 'flags' => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY ),
            'fileName'  =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED
        );
        /*
            modify the POST array based upon the filters and
            extract the values directly into variables.
        */
        $_POST=filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, $args );
        extract( $_POST );




        /*
            set options for dealing with XML. 
        */
        libxml_use_internal_errors( true ) ;
        $dom=new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
        $dom->recover=true;
        $dom->formatOutput=true;
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace=false;
        $dom->validateOnParse=false;
        $dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
        $dom->load( urldecode( $fileName ) );

        $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );

        
        /*
            Iterate through all POSTed items
        */
        foreach( $symbol as $index => $code ){
            /* Locate the relevant section within the XML based upon the tag */
            $loc=urldecode( $location[ $index ] );
            $expr=sprintf( '//HighwayRoutingData/tag[ contains( text(), "%s") ]', urldecode( $loc ) );
            $col=$xp->query( $expr );
            
            /* create the new symbol and add to the relevant `destinationSymbols` node */
            if( $col && $col->length > 0 && !empty( $code ) ){
                $symbol=$dom->createElement( 'string', $code );
                $dest=$xp->query( 'destinationSymbols', $col->item(0)->parentNode )->item(0);
                $dest->appendChild( $symbol );
            }
        }
        /* save the XML and redirect? */
        $dom->save( urldecode( $fileName ) );
    }
?>
    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Simple XML Processing...</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- 
            a single form should be OK and there is no need to repeat the
            `fileName` element as this is the same for each row in the table.
        -->
        <form method='post'>
            <table border=1 cellpadding='5px' cellspacing='2px'>
                <tr>
                    <th>Tag</th>
                    <th>Strings</th>
                    <th colspan=3>&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    
                    $file='RouteSymbol.xml';
                
                    libxml_use_internal_errors( true ) ;
                    /*
                        Load the XML file and build the HTML output
                    */
                    $dom=new DOMDocument();
                    $dom->validateOnParse=false;
                    $dom->recover=true;
                    $dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
                    $dom->load( $file );
                    libxml_clear_errors();
                    
                    
                    $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
                    $col=$xp->query('//HighwayRoutingData');
                    
                    
                    if( $col && $col->length > 0 ){
                        foreach( $col as $node ){
                            /*
                                find the `string` values and add to an array
                                which we will use to build a string later.
                            */
                            $output=array();
                            $strings=$xp->query( 'destinationSymbols/string', $node );
                            foreach( $strings as $string )$output[]=$string->nodeValue;
                            
                            /*
                                Find the tag for this node.
                            */
                            $tag=$xp->query('tag',$node)->item(0)->nodeValue;
                            
                            /*
                                Generate a new HTML table row with data found in this
                                node of the xml.
                            */
                            printf('
                                <tr>
                                    <td>%1$s</td>
                                    <td>%2$s</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" name="symbol[]" />
                                        <input type="hidden" name="location[]" value="%1$s" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td><input type="submit" value="ADD" /></td>
                                    <td><a href="#delete">Delete</a></td>
                                </tr>',
                                $tag,
                                implode( ', ', $output )
                            );
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </table>
            <input type='hidden' name='fileName' value='<?=$filename;?>' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I looked over the code and still could not figure out why blank strings are being appeneded to tags that I don't intend to append to.  IE if I add to a symbol to the first tag area it will add `<string></string>` to the rest of the tag categories

Comment: oops - sorry about that. Corrected the code now. `preserveWhiteSpace` should have been set as `false` and to prevent empty elements being added I simply added / forgot to add ` && !empty( $code )` prior to calling `createElement`